# How to fix Reports Size?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am newbie in using asp.net, I have a problem when it comes to reports sizing . I don't have any idea how to fix this, it should fill up the whole report viewer but it was stock on the right.

Do you know what property should I change I try anything but it's not working.. please help me :D, thanks in advance :D

Comment: Can you post yoour code please. Have you tried to set `Width="100%"`

Comment: Do you want to make your report viewer window smaller or your table larger?

Comment: @Alexander Galkin what paticular property in .rdlc or in report viewer??

Comment: @Alexander Galkin SQL Server 2005

Comment: @AlexanderGalkin I want to make the table larger like the size of my report viewer but it stock on the left??

Comment: Have a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can change the width of your table columns manually in the report designer. You have to set the `CanShrink` property of your columns to `false` to prevent them from collapsing in your application.

There is a known bug in SQL2005 reporting services that leads to column being rendered too small in some browsers. You have to upgrade your server to SP1 if this issue persists.